# How to access R.string.xxx resources from a method by passing string 'xxx' as parameter to that method?

Tags: java, android

I have many string elements in my `res/values/strings.xml`

So, I want one method `getString(String abc)` for retrieving the strings from `strings.xml`:

```
public String getString(String abc){ // abc = address1

    String result;

    result = context.getResources().getString(R.strings.+abc);
}
```

How to access the string elements in this method based on a String in argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public String getString(String abc){ // Ex. abc = "address1"

   int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(abc, "string",  getPackageName()); 

   return context.getResources().getString(resID);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 String abc="StringId";
 int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(abc, "string",  getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

try This:

```
Resources res = this.getResources(); 
 int resID = res.getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```